# Angular route error

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

i trying to do routing for two days but it i can't. I have reviewed the other questions on stackoverflow and i did everything they said in the answers but it wansn't. 
I call route script in to index.php

```
<script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
```

I wrote that code in to app.js;

```
var app = angular.module("app",['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl:'pages/home.php'
        }).
        when('/notificastions', {
            templateUrl:'pages/notifications.php'
        }).
        when('/messages', {
            templateUrl:'pages/messages.php'
        }).
        when('/search', {
            templateUrl:'pages/search.php'
        }).
        otherwise({
            rediectTo: '/'
        })
})
```

I wrote that codes in to a page with i connect ng-include:

```
<div id="ifmenu">
    <div class="ifmitem" href="#/home">Home</div>
    <div class="ifmitem" href="#/notifications">Notifications</div>
    <div class="ifmitem" href="#/messages">Messages</div>
</div>
<div ng-view></div>
```

But i get an error like this;

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.32/$injector/unpr?p0=%24templateRequestProvider%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24route
>       at angular.min.js:6
>       at angular.min.js:36
>       at Object.c [as get] (angular.min.js:34)
>       at angular.min.js:36
>       at c (angular.min.js:34)
>       at Object.d [as invoke] (angular.min.js:35)
>       at angular.min.js:36
>       at Object.c [as get] (angular.min.js:34)
>       at instantiateRoute (angular-route.js:886)
>       at Object.d [as invoke] (angular.min.js:35)

How do i resolve this error?

---

I resolve 'Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]' error, but have exclamation mark beside hashtag. Like this: (localhost/app/#!). And none of link doesn't working except the otherwise function.
I called solution of this problem in internet and i saw that i need to attach and i added;

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
```

But none of them doesn't working this time. What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: include angular.js instead of minified and update the screen shot of the error

Comment: btw you have got a typo in the configuration of your router: notificastions

Comment: @Aravind The error has disappeared, thank you :) But routing doesn't work. Have exclamation mark beside hashtag (localhost/#!/page)

Comment: that's cool. :)

Comment: I have a new problem. I updated my question. Would you be interested again? @Aravind

Comment: Of course, i sent a message :) @Aravind

Answer (score 0):

Your notifications spelling is wrong.see the routeProvider section

```
when('/notificastions', {
        templateUrl:'pages/notifications.php'
    })
```

notificastions should be notifications

Comment: I include angular.js instead of minified and error has disapperaed and i've fixed the typing error but routing doesn't work. Have exclamation mark beside hashtag. Like this: (localhost/file/#!/page)

Comment: Please correct the typo mistake in your route "notificastions should be notifications"

Comment: what is the sequence of your js.?
> it should be like angular.js then route.js

Comment: Like so, otherWise founction working but other when functions doesn't work

Comment: Try Like this var app = angular.module("app",[]);